# Grouping different join paths for similar objects

Tags: orm, sqlalchemy

Okay, so let's say I have a table of users

```
class User(ModelBase):
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
```

And some tables of transactions

```
class TransactionTypeA(ModelBase):
    amount = Column(Integer)
    timestamp = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)

    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(User.id))
    user = relationship(...)

class TransactionTypeB(ModelBase):
    amount = Column(Integer)
    timestamp = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)

    property_unique_to_b = ...
    user = relationship(to user via property_unique_to_b)
```

Is there a good way to create some parent Transaction table that *retains* the relationship to `User`, so I can just query `session.query(func.sum(AllTransactions.amount)).filter(User.id==some_id)`? The only way to create a table similar to this would be with [non-traditional mappings](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/nonstandard_mappings.html#mapping-a-class-against-arbitrary-selects) by mapping it to some `UNION ALL` select. If I use joined-table inheritance I remove the duplication of `timestamp` and `amount`, but I still can't get any global relationship of the transactions to the `User` table.

Comment: is transaction type matter or not? if not then yes you can create a table contains all transactions and user who do the transaction. `class Transactions(ModelBase): ... user_id = column(Integer, ForeignKey(User.id)` `class User(ModelBase): ... transactions = relationship('Transactions', backref='user')` now you can query: `select.query(func.sum(Transactions.amount)).filter(Transactions.user.id==some_user.id)` your Transactions table will have a user object. anymore.

Comment: but TransactionTypeB does not explictly have a foreign key to User.